# Solve for $x$ where: $x^2=2^x$

Tags: functions, newton-raphson

Solve for $x$ where: $$x^2=2^x$$

Graphing the function ($f(x)=x^2-2^x$) it is clear that there are three solutions.

Two of them are nice solutions. i.e. $x=2,4$

The graph shows a third solution at $x=-0.76666...$

I found this using the Newton-Raphson method but it took quite a few iterations.

What other methods are there for solving such a question?

Comment: I think he is looking for an alternative numerical method .

Comment: @Derek:http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~gerry/class/ME350/pdf/ME350_Lecture_05_slides_root-finding.pdf

Comment: @derek:there is some popular method to find $f(x)=0$ roots ,such as 
  Fixed point iteration
• Bisection
• Newton’s method
• Secant method

Comment: 2 by inspection; 4 by guess and check; the third one is goign to be difficult no matter what.

Comment: The negative solution is solution of $x=-e^{\ln2/2·x}$ or $-\ln2/2·x·e^{-\ln2/2·x}=\ln2/2$ so that with the Lambert-W function $\ln2/2·x=-W(\ln2/2)$. With solution $x=-0.76666469596212306$